# Syntax error while trying to get json return from server on different port than 80

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have json from a server `http://192.168.1.156:8025/json` returning:

```
{"arduino":[{"location":"outdoor","celsius":"0.00"}, {"location":"indoor","celsius":"24.30"}]}
```

however when I try to get it using `.ajax` to return it as html in div object,  I keep getting error saying

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error.

which looks like the error is coming due to colon before the port number ,

of the below html:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxCall_jquery.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://192.168.1.156:8025/json',
      data: {
         format: 'json'
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#info').html(data.arduino[1].celsius);
      },
      type: 'GET'
   });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="info"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i don't get any clue how it is a syntax error ?

Comment: You're receiving JSON, but telling jQuery to expect jsonp. Pick one.

Comment: I'm guessing you switched to JSONP because you were getting a cross-domain error when you tried JSON. But you can't just change the `dataType` option, you also have to change the server so that it sends the requested format instead of ordinary JSON.

Comment: right on @Barmar , I am hosting the client page running on HTTPS connection while data retrieved from JSON is an MCU is capable of handling HTTP only, ontop both are different domain , my MCU based server that returns json includes ` Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the header , what other changes I would need to make in client side or server side ?

Comment: If the server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, I think that should be all you need, you don't need to use JSONP.